# Updated state not displaying in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I have an application that adds team members to a business but am having trouble showing the new members when added. The app verifies the user exist on the backend and grabs all of their data when they are added. I can see that the members info has been added to the local state but it will not display it until I do a full refresh of the page. I've even tried updating the state using useEffect but nothing is working.

Add Team Member Component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {addTeamMember} from "../../../../redux/actions/business";

function BusinessPageMembers (props) {

const [allMembers, setAllMembers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setAllMembers(props?.business?.all_team_members)
},[props.business])

const addMember = () => {
    const user = email
    const profile = email
    const business = props.business.business_page.business
    const member_details = { roll, title, user, profile, business }
    props.addTeamMember(member_details)
    }

const Members = allMembers.map(members => (
    <div key={members.id}>
        <div>
             <Link className='team-member-name' to={`/profile/${members.slug}`}>{[members.first_name, ' ', members.last_name]}</Link>
             <h5>{members.email}</h5>
             <h6>{members.roll}</h6>
             <h6>{members.title}</h6>
         </div>))

return (
         <div>
                {Members}    
         </div>


    );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    business: state.business,
};
 }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addTeamMember})(BusinessPageMembers);
```

Add Team Member Redux Action:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {ADDING_TEAM_MEMBER,TEAM_MEMBER_ADDED,} from "./types";

export const addTeamMember = (member_details) => (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({ type: ADDING_TEAM_MEMBER })
   axios.post('/api/team-member/add/', member_details)
    .then(res => {
        dispatch ({
            type: TEAM_MEMBER_ADDED,
            payload: res.data
        })
    }).catch(err => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)))
}
```

Add Team Member Redux Reducer:

```
import {TEAM_MEMBER_ADDED, ADDING_TEAM_MEMBER} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
all_team_members: [],
adding_member: false,
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case ADDING_TEAM_MEMBER:
        return {
            ...state,
            adding_member: true
        }
    case TEAM_MEMBER_ADDED:
        return {
            ...state,
            all_team_members: [...state.all_team_members, action.payload],
            adding_member: false
        }
    case ALL_TEAM_MEMBERS:
        return {
            ...state,
            all_team_members: action.payload,
        }
    default:
        return state
}
}
```

[Page right after you hit add member](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnp84.jpg)

[The new member has been added to the new state but not being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bMSj.jpg)

[The page after doing a complete refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1a0C.jpg)

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Members are added via `props.addTeamMember`, i.e., a function passed to the component. `allMembers` is updated when `props.business` is updated (or the page is reloaded), and as local state, will be unaffected by parent component shenanigans. How are you expecting the member to be added to the local state?

Comment: What is `props.allMembers`? The component has an `allMembers` state that is updated via `props.business` selected from redux, but it's unclear what any other props are *other than* `addTeamMember` function. Please [edit] the post to include all relevant code as part of your complete [mcve].

Comment: Hey @DrewReese, thank you for replying. I edited the 'props' from allMembers since it was from a child component that I simplified and was not needed for this post. In the second image the local state is being updated but not being displayed. Could it be because the 'Members' is in a child component while allMembers is being updated in the parent?

Comment: I only see code for a `BusinessPageMembers` component. Your edit is now mapping the `allMembers` state, but nothing is returned from the `render` method. Can you [edit] to include all relevant code, and clarify what the parent/child components are?

Comment: @DrewReese, sorry about the confusion, I was trying to condense the code to a single component for the post. I ended up doing that on my end and got the same results as before. I also edited the errors in the render method.

Comment: So is the issue that there is some `state.business` Redux state/`allMembers` local state, and this `BusinessPageMembers` component dispatches `props.addTeamMember(member_details)` to add a member (*somewhere*).... and the `BusinessPageMembers` needs to display whatever was updated? If this is correct can you [edit] the post to include the redux code?

Comment: @DrewReese that is correct. I went ahead and added the redux code. Thank you for your patients.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see what is happening here. For some reason when you add a member the action payload object for a user is missing the `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` properties. I'm guessing when you reload the page you've some code fetching all the members, and this other API is returning different data, a.k.a. the data you actually want to render. Looks like your `/api/team-member/add/` endpoint needs to return response data that matches the other API that returns all the users.

Comment: Also, just because I'm pedantic, it's a "role" for a position/title someone fills on a team, not "roll" which is a noun (*something you eat like a dinner roll*) or a verb (*an action like rolling down a hill*).

Comment: @DrewReese WOW, yep it's a DRF issue. Thank you! And thanks for pointing out the spelling error, I've got a lot to fix.

Comment: Got it. In this case I'm voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" since the issue seems to be with the backend.